# Is this a right question for an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've just failed the triage audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/17591279).

I've marked it as *Unsalvageable* since, in my opinion:

- Just presented a picture to describe the expected result
- Does not show any effort
- No code posted
- Just a link to a help page without indication about how the example proposed in the page has been implemented
- No description of the problem: it simply *does not work*

Despite the above, the question has collected 6 upvotes.

My question is: Why that question has not to be considered *Unsalvageable*?

Comment: I think you got unlucky there. I have no idea why that question got that many upvotes. There's no MCVE, no shown effort other than the mention of a single class. It should've been closed as "Too broad".

Comment: According to the comments, this post had received a very well formulated and informative answer, which had been attracting positive attention. Seems to have lured the system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, that's a terrible audit, for all the reasons that you cited. "Unsalvageable" was the correct choice.

I have no idea why it was so massively upvoted by the community prior to it coming to your attention. As you can see in [the post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46241071/timeline), the votes came in scattered out over a few days, *after* an answer was accepted. Not sure if there's anything suspicious here or not; I will look into it. My *guess* is that the high quality of the answer attracted readers, who also upvoted the question.

Anyway, sometimes bad audits get selected. It is an algorithmic process, after all, and it's fed by the worst heuristic of all: human actions. :-)

If you fail a bad audit like this, the first thing to do is open the post in a new tab and *act on it as you ordinarily would*. That means, in this case, downvote it and vote to close it. Several different close reasons will do; don't agonize over the choice too much. I'm hoping that one of the 6 downvotes now there belongs to you. Unfortunately, none of the close votes is yours, but that has been handled since you brought it to the attention of Meta.

The reason that's important is it tells the system that the post is ***not*** a good audit candidate. As it turns out, you weren't the first person to be faced with this audit. Some folks chose "Requires Editing", which passed the audit, but at least three people who correctly indicated "Unsalvageable" flunked. The one *blatantly incorrect* review on this post was when it was in the "First Posts" queue, and someone said "No Action Needed". Unfortunately, that wasn't an audit...so the system didn't know it was the wrong choice.

You aren't currently banned from review (and neither are any of the other victims), so nothing more to do here, really.

Comment: Does the system specifically register the fact that you performed some actions on a post, where you failed an audit? Does it raise some kind of _"Maybe a bad audit"_ flag?

Comment: No, I don't think the logic is anywhere near that complex. And I know there is no "disputed audit" flag (but [there probably should be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790)). However, downvotes and close votes will *quickly* cause a post to lose its "known good" status, and stop it from being chosen as an audit. @Cerbrus

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer and for the suggestion on how to proceed in such cases.

Comment: The question is now at 16 downvotes (-10 net) and falling.